# SSRS Report, Report, rdlc

Tags: reporting-services, report, rdlc

I am looking for a way to display letters inside a s![like shown in the image][1]quare box in the .rdlc file. For eg: if I want to display "101" in report, each letters will be displayed inside a square box. Is there any way we can do this in rdlc?

Comment: Not really an answer per se because I don't have the necessary files or know how to do it, but I think probably the easiest way to do this would be to download an appropriate font and use that in report builder.

Comment: Thanks Dan for replying !!!

Comment: Thanks Dan for replying !!! I googled and found a font which matches my requirement. Thanks again!!!!